# Exported function not found in another script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a unix script that has the structure below. Basically, I want to have a "Library" script of functions that I use all the time, and export all the functions using `export -f functionName`.  The actual script using the library functions would first run the library script to perform the export commands and would then theoretically have access to the functions just exported.  However, this does not work as shown by the error.  Both scripts have been `chmod 777`'ed for testing.  I am literally trying these examples below.  These are not substitutes for some prod code somewhere. I copied and pasted what I am trying.

LibraryFunctions.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getHelloWorldString() {
    echo "Hello World"
} 
export -f getHelloWorldString
```

TestLibraryFunctions.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

./LibraryFunctions.sh

function testExportedHelloWorld () {
    echo $(getHelloWorldString)
}
testExportedHelloWorld
```

Result:

```
me@myHost:~/testDir $ ./TestLibraryFunctions.sh
./TestLibraryFunctions.sh: line 6: getHelloWorldString: command not found
```

**Edit: Solution that worked for me:**

Removed `export -f getHelloWorldString` from LibraryFunctions.sh

Removed `./LibraryFunctions.sh`from TestLibraryFunctions.sh

Added `source LibraryFunctions.sh`from TestLibraryFunctions.sh at the top

-------  New files ------:

LibraryFunctions.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getHelloWorldString() {
    echo "Hello World"
}
```

TestLibraryFunctions.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source LibraryFunctions.sh

function testExportedHelloWorld () {
    echo $(getHelloWorldString)
}
testExportedHelloWorld
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Change to `. ./LibraryFunctions.sh` and things should start to work.

Comment: The `export` is not needed in this case. It makes functions available in sub-shells, something you are not using here.

Comment: As Harald indicated you are running `LibraryFunctions.sh` as a script in its own right so it is running in its own shell session. You need to source (`.`) it into the current shell session for its `export`ed functions and variables to be visible.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer - post the answer as a proper, separate answer (if it substantially adds to existing answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting a variable or function only makes it available in child processes of the shell that performed the `export`. When you execute a command, including running a shell script, that script runs in a child process. So you're running `LibraryFunctions.sh` in a child of the original `TestLibraryFunctions.sh` process. When you get back to the original script, you're not in a child of `LibraryFunctions.sh`, so exported functions are not visible.

If you want to run a shell script in the same process as the current process, use the `source` or `.` command to execute it.

```
source LibraryFunctions.sh
```

Note that if you do this, you don't need to `export` the function, since the definition happens in the same shell process, and there are no child shell processes that need to use it.

Comment: I just realized that this is an even better solution that I had hoped for because now I dont have to manage exporting all these function.