# How to open xterm -e 'command', preserving already declared functions?

Tags: linux, bash, function, xterm

### I would like to run the following command:

```sh
$ testfunction (){ echo 123;}
$ xterm -hold -e "testfunction"
```

> returns: testfunction command not found (in the new xterm window).

but when I call the function in main terminal, it returns 123

```sh
$ testfunction
123
```

### Tried

In `declare -F | grep testfunction` I can see that the function is declared.

Tried to declare just a variable:

```sh
$ variable='123'
$ xterm -hold -e "echo $variable"
```

> returns: 123 (in new xterm).

Why new oppened xterm doesn't found declared functions, but found declared variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting a function in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885871/608639), [Exported function not found in another script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37034651/608639), [Sub-shell process not be able to access variables and functions defined in parent shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52138261/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export functions/variables to let child processes access them.

```
testfunction() { echo 123; }
export -f testfunction
xterm -hold -e "testfunction"
```

[image: result]

And, `xterm -hold -e "echo $variable"` doesn't work actually, it just looks like so. `$variable` is in double quotes and thus expanded before calling `xterm`, i.e its value is passed to `xterm`, `xterm -hold -e 'echo $variable'` wouldn't work since `variable` is not exported.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `xterm -e "echo $variable"` runs security risks. If `variable='$(rm -rf ~)'`, someone running that command will have a very, very bad day; whereas `export variable` and then running `xterm -e 'echo "$variable"'` is safe.

Comment: Do you know why it recognize variables even if I do not export them?

Comment: Sorri for editing, I double click somewere and an image appears and I save by mistake... clicking too fast

Comment: Understand now. Thank you again!

Comment: No, it is perfect, my page loaded slowly and then I double clicked, and it appears in editing, then I tought I print screen area by mistake and add it into. Sorry.